# Laravel and vue: require is not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

In Laravel version 6 the follwing error happens with vue in the console:

`app.js:24703 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined 
 at app.js:24703`

the error points to:

```
require('./bootstrap');
```

Webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.scripts([
'resources/js/jquery-3.4.1.js',
'resources/js/bootstrap.min.js',
'resources/js/toastr.js',
'resources/js/vue.js',
'resources/js/axios.js',
'resources/js/app.js'
], 'public/js/app.js')
.styles([
'resources/css/bootstrap.min.css',
'resources/css/toastr.css'

], 'public/css/app.css');
```

It works fine VUEJS for me but it doesn’t allow me to add components

Also another thing that I notice is that this error disables me vue devtools.
The code is newly installed, both the Laravel and Vue project and if I create a new project I get the same error.

```
        require('./bootstrap');

    window.Vue = require('vue');

    Vue.component('message', require('./components/message.vue').default);


    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data:{
            message: ''
        },
        methods:{
            send(){
                if(this.message.length !=0){
                    console.log(this.message);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you upgrade to Laravel 6 from a previous version? I don't recognize mix.scripts, it's mix.js in Laravel 6

Comment: The installation is new. And regarding scripts I saw it in an instructional and I use it without inconvenience. Based on your comment I changed scripts to js also the error persists. I think the problem comes through webpack because it happens to me also with a clean laravel installation

Comment: And you've run npm (or yarn) install after adding the laravel/ui package?

Comment: If you are asked to update with npm install && npm run dev

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like, somehow, the file is given to the browser hasn't been compiled.

You need to change the configuration `Webpack.mix.js`

You can try change `mix.scripts([])` on `mix.js([])` and add `.vue()`.
It helped me.

```
mix.js([
    'resources/js/jquery-3.4.1.js',
    'resources/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    'resources/js/toastr.js',
    'resources/js/vue.js',
    'resources/js/axios.js',
    'resources/js/app.js'
], 'public/js/app.js') .vue();
```